# HttpSessionAttributeListener and HttpSessionBindingListener

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

When i read the doc, both seems to be the same. Then what is the difference between these two? Please explain the difference between the two with an example like in which scenario which to be used.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a generic listener to the session. It's called whenever an attribute of any kind is being added or removed to/from a session. It's used when you want to be informed of any session attribute addition/removal.

The second one is a callback interface that can be implemented by a specific class. The callback method is called on an object implementing this interface when this object is being bound/unbound to/from the session. It's used when you want an object to be informed of its own addition/removal to/from the session.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When i remove an attribute from a session, then the unbound method is not getting executed. Then when will the unbound method get executed?

Comment: Show us the code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Without code, I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpSessionBindingListener:
```

If an object implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`, it is notified when it is bound to or unbound from a session. For example,

```
MyObject implements HttpSessionBindingListener
{
// class definition
}
```

If I call

```
session.setAttribute ("Object", MyObject)
```

methods `valueBound` and/or `valueUnbound` (defined in `HttpSessionBindingListener`, implemented in `MyObject` are called)
Implementing `HttpSessionBindingListener` works only for the object that implements it

`HttpSessionAttributeListener`:
When any class implements `HttpSessionAttributeListener` interface it is notified when any change in the attribute list of session occurs. For example

```
MyClass implements HttpSessionAttributeListener
{
// implementations of methods
}
session.setAttribute ("anything", AnyObjectNotOnlyMyClass);
```

indicates change in the list of attributes.Implementing `HttpSessionAttributeListener` listens to any attribute added, removed or replaced.